# On running my selenium python script, i am getting processed finished with exit code 0 in the console but my results are not showing up

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Nothing is getting printed in console on running the script. Browser is not launching

In console- Process finished with exit code (0)
Script -

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pytest
import time
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager


def test_google():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    assert driver.title == 'Sign in – Google accounts'
    print(driver.title)
```

Comment: As you are using Pytest. Please run the test using `pytest -v <test_file_name.py>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created the method but didn't call the method that's why i think

Comment: You don't need to call the test method explicitly. Just running `pytest -v test_file.py` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers . But i was able to solve the problem in 2 ways :

1. Calling the method solved it
2. I reinstalled everything and then run it . it worked